# How can I put 2 scenario's with more then 1 flow in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

Customer has 2 scenario's. Both have more then 1 flow.
For example.

1. Tickets
   a. Buy Tickets: 1500 concurrent users
   b. Browse the website: 1500 concurrent users
2. View
   a. Flow 1: 750 concurrent users
   b. Flow 2: 750 concurrent users
   c. Search the website: 500 concurrent users
   Scenario 1 must be run before scenario 2 can be run.

Now is my question: how can I put this in Jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should use different [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to represent different groups of business users. If you need one Thread Group to be executed before the other(s) either go for [setUp Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) or tick `Run Thread Groups consecutively` on [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) level, this way Thread Groups will be executed upside down

[image]

If you need yet another level of distribution inside the Thread Group you can use [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) which controls how often its children will be executed. So if you put 3 flows under 2nd Thread Group you can use:

- 2000 threads (virtual users) in total
- Throughput Controller 1 - 37.5% of threads will be executing flow b
- Throughput Controller 2 - 37.5% of threads will be executing flow c
- Throughput Controller 3 - 25% of threads will be searching website

Example test plan outline:

[image]

More information: [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability)

Comment: Thank you very much Dmitir T.  And I also like the way that you did visualize it.  That did help even more.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to note that, although the mentioned techniques will work in terms of configuring the number of VUsers, they will not guarantee that the **Avg TPS** per requests will match the same proportion. I've mentioned this in another post:

"It's common a misconception when trying to achieve a targeted percentage of requests to instantiate Vusers in the same proportion. This only works if the Avg Response Time (ART) of each type of request is the same. It's very unlikely that, for example, the search request ART will the same RT as the registration request. As a consequence, after executing the test for a certain amount of time the actual proportion of requests (of each type) will be the different than the targeted request proportion."